# Frame problem when using with a third-party node

Tags: ros, frame, world, laser-scan-matcher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using laser_scan_matcher node to be working with my node. The problem I'm now having is that I've my `/world` defined somewhere in my code. In laser_scan_matcher, I need to set the value for `publish_tf` as `true`, or else, it'll complaint. I can set `publish_tf` as `true`, but then, the output and the robot movement is really weird or wrong. Whenever I try to set the `publish_tf` as `false`, I receive the following serious warning:

```
[ WARN] [1329318619.876324732]: Warning: Frame id /world does not exist! Frames(3):Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT.
```

Without the laser_scan_matcher node, my own node works out-of-the-box. I've also seen the code of laser_scan_matcher, they also define "world" frame. Do they clash? Any idea how to resolve this?

**EDIT**

In my broadcaster node:

```
static tf::TransformBroadcaster tfb;
tf::Transform xform;
xform.setOrigin(tf::Vector3(previous_poseLD2_.pose.position.x-starting_position_x, previous_poseLD2_.pose.position.y-starting_position_y, previous_poseLD2_.pose.position.z));
xform.setRotation(tf::Quaternion(previous_poseLD2_.pose.orientation.x, previous_poseLD2_.pose.orientation.y, previous_poseLD2_.pose.orientation.z, previous_poseLD2_.pose.orientation.w));
tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time::now(), "/world", "/base_link"));
```

In another node:

```
tfListener_.waitForTransform("/world", "/laser", ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(20.0));
```

On top of that, I have a static transform publisher from base_link to laser.

BTW, I'm specifically interested to use the pose information(x, y and delta) to be integrated with my node.

Here is the laser_scan_matcher xml:

```
 <node pkg="laser_scan_matcher" type="laser_scan_matcher_node" name="laser_scan_matcher_node" output="screen">  
   <param name="use_alpha_beta" value="true"/>     
   <param name="max_iterations" value="10"/>    
   <param name="publish_tf" value="false"/>   
 </node>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27668/frame-problem-when-using-with-a-third-party-node/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2012-02-15

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-02-15**:
How often does this warning appear? Is it only one time? Or is it continuous?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
It's continuous but not frequent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Let's examine the frames `laser_scan_matcher` works with:

- the *sensor frame* - typically this is "/laser"
- the *base frame* - typically this is `/base_link`
- the *world frame* - typically this is `world` (or sometimes `odom`)

The tf from the *base frame* to the *sensor frame* is assumed to be static. It should be published by a [static TF publisher](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher)

The tf from the *world frame* to the *base frame* will be published by *laser_scan_matcher*, and will represent the moving pose of the robot in the world.

If you publish a tf from `/world` to `/base_link` in your code (and the `publish_tf` param is true), that will result in a conflict with the scan matcher, since `base_link` now has two parents.

I might be able to provide more help if you describe your usage scenario and what your node is doing.

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
I've updated as above. Thanks anyway for getting involved.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
I could see as well, it's kinda conflict. Previously, I got a 3D .point cloud, but after integrating your node, I got 2D cloud, and the robot was strangely moving.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
I think for the publish_tf param, I can set to false, because I don't need the one from your node I think. Anyway, I'm opened to any fix.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-02-15**:
Where is xform coming from (how is it computed)? Also, the can matcher is meant to work with laser data (2d). What 3d cloud do you have?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
Kindly refer to EDIT part, because I've just added some more info.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
@Ivan Dryanovski: Should I set a fixed_frame param in the laser_scan_matcher's xml? At the moment, I didn't set it.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
previous_poseLD2_.pose.position.x is computed by taking the difference of the current and previous value of y-value of pose2D and accordingly for x-component. I integrate this difference value over time.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
Do I have some other frame conflict like, I defined static transform publisher(laser->base) differently from yours in terms of parameter values and so on?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-02-15**:
Is there any reason to take the difference and then integrate? This would just give you the pose that the laser publishes. Are you trying to remove a constant initial offset?

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
"This would just give you the pose that the laser publishes.." yes, I use this pose to be integrated with my initial pose. Any idea to resolve this frame conflict?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-02-16**:
Have the scan_matcher publish a pose, but not a tf (by setting the params). Then (in your node) subscribe to the pose message, do your calculations, and publish a tf. This way, only one world->base_link tf is published, and there are no conflicts.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-16**:
I did the step you suggested, but, it still ends up with this error message "[ WARN] [1329401873.937791965]: Warning: Frame id /world does not exist! Frames (3): Frame /laser exists with parent /base_link.
Frame /base_link exists with parent NO_PARENT."

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-16**:
I think I have a problem with setting the /world frame id. I'll resolve this one first.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`laser_scan_matcher` does not define the `/world` frame. By convention, the `/world` frame is never defined. `laser_scan_matcher` requires that a transform from `/base_link` exist. If you do not publish this transform, `laser_scan_matcher` can for you. This would represent the sensor's travel with respect to the world.

The frame `/world` is simply the default. If you would like to measure the robot's travel with respect to the `/map` frame, you only need to change the `fixed_frame` parameter. If you do not want to publish tf from `laser_scan_matcher`, simply change the `fixed_frame` to some static frame you use in your code (`/map` for example).

---

Originally posted by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) with karma: 11163 on 2012-02-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
I defined already the transform of base_link with respect to world like this: " tfb.sendTransform(tf::StampedTransform(xform, ros::Time::now(), "/world", "/base_link"));"

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2012-02-15**:
And from /laser wrt /world like this:"tfListener_.waitForTransform("/world", "/laser", ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(20.0));"  Am I missing anything else?

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-02-15**:
@alfa_80: Those tf's will likely result in a conflict - see my answer